# Dynamically Add Images to jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a plugin which I need to bind data to it from the code behind, dynamically.
I can use this:

```
var a = [{"image":"../../1.jpg","caption":"","title":"Image 1"},
{"image":"../../2.jpg","caption":"","title":"Image 2"},
{"image":"../../3.jpg","caption":"","title":"Image 3"},
        ];
$(".pikachoose").PikaChoose({ data: a });
```

but how can I create this VAR in code behind?
there I can loop as many times as I need and make as many images that i need but here no.

I also tried

```
<asp:DataList ID="lstThumbs" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="thumbs">
             <a href="">
               <img id="imgbtnThumb" src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' /></a>                         
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList></li>
```

but it doesn't show the images
i dont know why?!

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

In code behind, you can do:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this, "loadimgs", "var a = [..];$(".pikachoose").PikaChoose({ data: a });", true);
```

I may be missing a few parameters...  you can also use the scriptManager:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(..);
```

These methods write javascript to the client; you can write the array definition and the JQuery plugin script from the server.

Also, your markup doesn't have the pikachoose CSS class defined... could that be the problem?

Comment: thank you for the answer but i don't understand your codes really, can you be more precise? the css is not the problem.
i also think there must be a way to use a repeater in the html, but i don't know how

Comment: You can render JavaScript from the server very easily, using one of the two statements above, which I thought was the problem?  A repeater generates HTML, but can't be used in it, per se.  What are you trying to do, it's hard to understand...

Comment: i finally did it! a repeater did the trick
 <ul id="pikame" class="jcarousel-skin-pika">
        <asp:Repeater ID="lstThumbs" runat="server">
          
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <img src='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>

Comment: thanks alot! its difficult to explain, i just tried many things, but thanks for the help :-)